# Console log JSON result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm just starting to learn about APIs, JSON, and Jquery and I am stuck. How would I console log the following from my Jquery call -

name: "The Old Mill Cafe"

Here's my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mainbutton").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?entity_id=Chicago%2C%20IL%20&entity_type=city",
      headers: {
        "X-Zomato-API-Key": "…"
      },
      method: "GET"
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `console.log` is telling you that `data` is an object with a property called `restaurants` which is an array with a single entry. That entry is an object with a property called `restaurant` which is an object with a property called `name`. So:

```
console.log(data.restaurants[0].restaurant.name);
```

Comment: Thank you T.J. I'm taking a look at it now and appreciate the feedback on using Overstack. Being my first question asked I'll take it as a learning experience for next time.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are getting list of restaurants which has attributes like name and so on.

To get one restaurant you have to get first element of data

**data[0]** this will give you first restaurant of the list.

Now you need to get the name of the first restaurant to do that

**data[0].name**

So to get the name of the first restaurant you have to use following

**console.log(data[0].name);**